# Why is there nonzero change in magnetic flux with a moving bar?

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

Consider that this conductor passes across uniform magnetic field with uniform velocity. The thing that is confusing me is that, if the conductor is moving across a magnetic field with uniform velocity, then wouldn't the conductor be displacing equal magnetic field region in equal intervals of time? And shouldn't the change in magnetic flux be zero? If not, why?

Comment: Hint:  In the first case, there is no current 'round a close path while, in the second case (as usually presented), there *is* a current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't talk about flux in the first case because flux requires an area for the magnetic field to pass through. What you have is a collection of charges moving through a magnetic field. According to the Lorentz Force, positive charges are deflected one way, and negative charges the other, so you get the polarization shown in the diagram.

In the case of the rail, there is a change in the area the magnetic field passes through (positive or negative depending on the direction of the conductor's velocity). Thus you have change in flux and emf.

Comment: So if I am correct it means that no emf is generated based upon Faraday law because it is passing through magnetic field in such a way that no change in flux occurs